# Найти элементы на странице и взять их value jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу найти все `input` в `div` и вывести их значения?

```html
<div>
<input type="hidden" value="1">
<input type="hidden" value="2">
<input type="hidden" value="3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если с jQuery:

```js
$('div input').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>


<div>
  <input type="hidden" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" value="2">
  <input type="hidden" value="3">
</div>
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста еще, как я могу записать значения в переменную?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду добавить полученные value в массив?

Comment: Что Вы хотите получить в итоге?)

Comment: Желательно получить переменную с значениями 1, 2, 3. Мне эти данные передавать ajax post, так что как посоветуете? Сделать массив и на стороне php распарсить? Или сделать string и так же распарсить?

Comment: Точно не подскажу, но  https://itchief.ru/lessons/javascript/jquery-serialize-form `$.ajax({
      .... 
      data: $(this).val(), .... `

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин Или Вы можете добавлять в массив значения, как уточнила Humster, а потом через `JSON.stringfy` массив переводить в строку и отправлять в `ajax`.

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let div = document.querySelector('div').children;
    [...div].forEach(function (c) {
        console.log(c.value);
    })
})
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="hidden" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" value="3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Например вот так

```js
 var item = $("input[type='hidden']");
 item.each(function(){
 console.log($(this).attr('value'));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" value='1'>
<input type="hidden" value='2'>
<input type="hidden" value='3'>
```